# Does the acceleration of the sound source affect the Doppler shift in its frequency?

Tags: acoustics

So I am at an impasse regarding this.

Assume that there’s a source of sound moving towards a stationary observer. The source is accelerating uniformly.

Does the Doppler effect on the frequency recorded only depend on the speed of the source at the exact moment when the sound was emitted? Or does acceleration factor into it somehow? If so, how?

It would be really great if someone could clear this up. I have tried other means of searching for an answer to no avail.

Comment: Are you also concerned about the possible effect on the Doppler shift of the third, fourth, fifth, etc. time derivatives of position? Or only the second derivative?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.